# Customising Django Admin Interface

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django Admin, in the changelist view there is a `Add <model_name>` button at the top right hand corner.

Does anyone have any idea how to change the default text in that button?

*UPDATE*

I want to change the word `Add` to something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changelist view renders the change_list.html file in django/contrib/admin/templates/admin directory.

Specifically, the snippet that you want to modify is

```
{% block content %}
  <div id="content-main">
    {% block object-tools %}
      {% if has_add_permission %}
        <ul class="object-tools">
          {% block object-tools-items %}
            <li>
              <a href="add/{% if is_popup %}?_popup=1{% endif %}" class="addlink">
                {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endblock %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

So the bad news is that your "Add" user interface string as you can see is hardcoded.

The good news is, you can still override it by creating your own change_list.html template in your own project templates/admin/ directory.  The specifics are explained here in django docs:-
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

and specifically in your case, it is simply to override the object-tools block on your own change_list.html file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your Django admin templates. The template you're looking for is `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html`. Look for `addlink`, the line below that should be the word to change.

Answer (score 0):

that's the name for your model.

Django use model's class name by default, but you can change it by **Meta.verbose_name**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"a_new_name"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I came across verbose_name as well but I did not make myself clear in my question. I want to to change the entire text.